# webapp unresponsive after argelius' favorite-star

Tags: javascript, ios, github, web-component

after using [argelius' favorite star](https://github.com/argelius/favorite-star) in an iOS webapp its js becomes unresponsive. In desktop safari it works but gives the error `Refused to get unsafe header "Location"`, after digging around that seems to be unrelated but I thought I should mention it.

Any ideas?

Maybe something is wrong in the way I implemented it, this is the first GitHub repository I implement.

this code is in `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://argelius.github.io/favorite-star/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://argelius.github.io/favorite-star/favorite-star.html">
```

**EDIT:** after using iOS web inspector I found that `scope.wrappers.Window` returned `null`, digging further I found this solution:

change:

```
function getDescriptor(source, name) {
  try {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
  } catch (ex) {
    return dummyDescriptor;
  }
}
```

for:

```
function getDescriptor(source, name) {
  try {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
    if (desc) return desc;
  } catch (ex) {
    // Just return a dummy descriptor
  }
  return dummyDescriptor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using iOS web inspector I found that `scope.wrappers.Window` returned `null`, digging further I found this solution:

change:

```
function getDescriptor(source, name) {
  try {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
  } catch (ex) {
    return dummyDescriptor;
  }
}
```

for:

```
function getDescriptor(source, name) {
  try {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
    if (desc) return desc;
  } catch (ex) {
    // Just return a dummy descriptor
  }
  return dummyDescriptor;
}
```

credit: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/628

Answer (score -1):

Follow the installation procedure in https://github.com/argelius/favorite-star
and don't use the location "https://argelius.github.io/favorite-star/favorite-star.html".

Install it in your local environment then add the local path of the favorite-star.html.

I tried it with my local environment -

here is my html code -

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="import" href="favorite-star/favorite-star.html">
</head>
<body>
    Hi!!!  This is my favorite <favorite-star active></favorite-star>
</body>
</html>
```

and the extracted folder path is my static assets folder ie public and then the path mentioned in href.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how but I only find pages where they assume you know how this works... how do I install with nom or bower?

Comment: Do you have npm in your local environment ?

Comment: I have no Idea, I code with eclipse and host my site through openshift.

Comment: If you don't have npm in your local environment then download the zip from the link https://github.com/argelius/favorite-star/archive/master.zip , extract it in your local environment add the path from there.

Comment: http://sam.apostel.be/TAD/favorite-star-master/ this is what I get... before it did work on safari, now it doesn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151960/discussion-between-sam-apostel-and-rakesh-chouhan).